# Low pressure when using outside hose

Tags: plumbing, water-pressure, well, well-pump

We are in the northeast on a well. We have had no issues with inside water pressure or running out of water. Recently,
On two occasions, we filled a 240 gal inflatable pool from the outside hose. Around the time the pool was totally filled, we tried to run water inside the house. The first time, the bathroom sink upstairs went to just a trickle. The second time, we had more water, but it was definitely at a much, much reduced pressure. We have a submersible pump and a 40 gal or so pressure tank in basement. Does this indicate a problem with the well, the pump, the tank, or something else? We have never had any problems before this, and we have not had any problems since, when using water inside the house for every day use.

Correction: size of tank appears to be 20 gal

Comment: Check the pressure tank first.  If it's water-logged then it will not do what it's supposed to do and buffer the water at the house.  (Are you sure it's 40 gal?  That's relatively large for a pressure tank.  Usually they are 5-7 gal.)  It's quite possible that the well and/or pump are not able to provide the flow you are asking for when filling pools and such.  That may explain the large pressure tank.

Comment: A 5 -7 gallon tank is tiny, a 40 gallon was quite common in the past. With a bladder tank on a country property I almost always use 25 gallon. If the water is on outside hose bibs have higher flow rates than inside faucets. With a large quantity of water used in 1 shot it is more likely you are reaching your max flow rare.